# Retrieve part of json file from an external website (sparkfun)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This question might be quite specific to sparkfun, but I still wish to make it as a general question due to my limited experience in javascript.

I have been using the follow html and javascript (d3.js) file to load json data from [sparkfun data server](http://data.sparkfun.com):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data_sensor;
var url =   "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/w5nEnw974mswgrx0ALOE.json"
d3.json(url,  function (error,json) {
    if (error) throw error;
    data_sensor=json;
    console.log(data_sensor)
}) 
</script>

</body>
```

After running the script, i will end up with all data array stored in variable *data_sensor* for post-analyse.

What i wish to do now is to create a dash board that **downloads and stores only the latest value**. i understand that i could just use the first value in the *data_sensor* to do so (i.e., data_sensor[0]) but such method becomes quite inefficient with the growth of data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I've wanted to load JSON from somewhere I've always used jQuery:

Import jQuery like this:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can do something like this to get your JSON file:

```
var data_sensor;
var url = "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/w5nEnw974mswgrx0ALOE.json"
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  data_sensor = data;
  console.log(data_sensor)
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks jake, i tried your script, it says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: got it. i need to download jquery first or use CDN

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert here, but their docs state tat you can use paging to get the first 250kb of data:

```
var url = "https://data.sparkfun.com/output/w5nEnw974mswgrx0ALOE.json?page=1";
```

You can get your first object/set of data, and I'm afraid there's no general way to take only part of any API response - request is request, it could send you every possible data depending on architecture, from "OK" string to 200MB of data. Carefully reading docs is your best bet.